# PDE course question

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question

What courses do I need for a course in partial differential equations? My university has a prereq of Multivariate Calculus and Ordinary Differential Equations. However, I opened up a book on pdes in my university library, and it said that the student is assumed to have a course in modern algebra.

Comment: if it helps, this is the course description: Method of characteristics for quasilinear first-order equations, complete integral, Cauchy-Kowalewsky theory, classification of second-order equations in two variables, canonical forms, difference methods of hyperbolic and parabolic equations, and Poisson integral method for elliptic equations.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly university dependent, but I think a strong calculus foundation on top of ODEs is all you really need as prerequisites. Maybe modern algebra helps, but for a first course in odes you really don't need that much. many techniques are straightforward applications of regular differential equations concepts such as separation of variables. Then again, you can teach PDES from a much more abstract framework in which just ODEs and calc might not be enough... Go speak with the professor teaching the course.

Answer (score 2):

If your university says those are the prereqs, then those are the prereqs.  The course will be designed for students who have had Multivariate Calculus and Ordinary Differential Equations.  If you want more information, ask the instructor or your faculty advisor.